# Connecting Adjacency Matrix to a Separate Class

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array

I am working on a project where I am tracking the passes that occur between players in soccer and then building an Adjacency Matrix that I can analyze to obtain data about the team as a whole and about the players as individuals (e.g. The [connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)) of the team during a certain game or the [betweeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) of a player with the goal). To implement this, I have written three different classes in C++: Team, Player, and AdjacencyMatrix.

- Player holds the identification information (number and last name) and the data that is already calculated for that player (betweenness, number of touches, etc)
- AdjacencyMatrix is a class defined to make a square two dimensional array of ints that has member functions defined to find the connectivity, betweenness, etc..
- Team holds an array of Players (the roster), the data on the whole team, and the AdjacencyMatrix storing all of the passes between the Players

I am wondering if you have any ideas on how to keep the indices stored in an AdjacencyMatrix connected with the Players in the roster of a Team. Currently, I assume that the index of Player A in the roster is the same as the index of Player A in the AdjacencyMatrix, but I feel like that is very flimsy, especially since I would like to be importing/exporting this data (the AdjacencyMatrix as well as all the calculated data) to and from files for storage.

Another idea that I had was to add a member variable in the Player class that stores that Player's index in the Team's AdjacencyMatrix. This idea would be more robust than my current solution (you would be able to mess with the order of the roster without losing information), but it seems very inelegant.

Do you have any more elegant solutions to this problem or should I just be satisfied with the slightly inelegant but more robust solution?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Are you asking about the algorithm, or just how to make a graph in the first place? The graph nodes will represent a player, but how they do that is not particularly important. Having the index of the player in another data structure makes you have to know about that other data structure, but if it's just a fixed roster of players then the index doesn't sound too risky.

Comment: That's the difficulty. The roster of players is relatively permanent, but they might change in between games depending on if the team makes any trades, drafts, etc. I am looking for a way to connect each player with an index that is flexible enough to add/drop players when I need to.

Comment: Either way, you want to use or make a graph library that doesn't care about the outside info in the nodes and edges. Just plug in the data. Keep it as independent as possible. For game reports, copy all the player info into the node, so that future roster changes are irrelevant. For end-of-season reports, I would use the unique db identifier for each player -- personnel and jersey numbers may change, but once a player gets a unique db identifier, they always have it, even if they leave the team.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot.